# Flutter pick image camera or gallery exception

Tags: flutter, firebase-mlkit

I have a Flutter project in which I am trying to put MLKit for text OCR. 
I have crated a standalone Flutter project which works fine with MLKit. However when I put the same code and dependencies to my existing Flutter project it is not working as expected.

Below are the issues I am getting when trying to choosing the image...

1. When I click on the gallery to choose the image it throws exception.

   final file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
     if (file == null) {
       throw Exception('File is not available');
     }
2. When I am trying to choose camera it asks for the permission for the first time and then app gets closed.... throws " **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**"
3. Once these exceptions thrown every subsequent tries it throws exception "**PlatformException(already_active, image picker is already active, null)**"

   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
    firebase_auth: ^0.8.0+1
    cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0
    firebase_core: ^0.3.0
    intl_translation: ^0.17.2
    firebase_messaging: ^3.0.0
    http: ^0.12.0+1
    xml: ^3.3.1
    firebase_storage: ^2.0.0
    uuid: ^1.0.3
    shared_preferences: ^0.5.0
    flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.2.7
    google_sign_in: ^4.0.0
    flutter_signin_button: ^0.2.5
    mlkit: ^0.9.0
    path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
    image_picker: ^0.5.0+3

I have followed below blog in order to implement MLKit https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-text-barcode-scanner-app-with-firebase-ml-kit-103db6b6dad7

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete the `build` folder in your project. Once you do it and you start your project again, it will work.

Answer (score 4):

use [image_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) plugin

```
var imageSource;
if (source == CAMERA_SOURCE) {
  imageSource = ImageSource.camera;
} else {
  imageSource = ImageSource.gallery;
}

try {
  final file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
  if (file == null) {
    throw Exception('File is not available');
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and help. I am using this plugin only.

Answer (score 3):

Try cleaning your app, use `Flutter clean` command.

Many times I have faced this sort of issues where there were no issue related to code and still something went wrong, but somehow `Flutter clean` tends to help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, the problem could be with the permissions, you need to add [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) for accessing the hardware like camera or storage etc.

Secondly try other application for camera other than the default app in our phone.